# autofocus attribute for Struts2 <s:textField> + Auto focus not working in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, html, struts2

This is regarding adding auto focus attribute in `s: tag` element `textfield`.

I want the textfield to be highlighted on page load.

Html tag `<input>` has autofocus but that does not work in s:textfield.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>
```

**EDIT**

Increasing the scope of the problem. Changing the Subject of the question **(Rev)**

Now, I am using jQuery to handle this problem.
Below script is working fine in Firefox but not working in Chrome.

```
$('name["fname"]').focus();
```

Appreciate help in this regard.

Comment: Isn't this a question about HTML?

Comment: no I have not tagged it. it is about struts2 s: tag

Comment: @handle changed the question and increased the scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the edited part of my question.

Below code fixed chrome browser issue.

```
setTimeout(function(){$('name["fname"]').focus();},100);
```

Read on for those who have faced similar issue. http://fellowtuts.com/jquery/jquery-focus-not-working-in-chrome/

Comment: Are you executing it inside the jquery ready event? `$(function () { $('[name="fname"]').focus(); });`